# Ask a DNS server what sites it hosts - and how to possibly prevent misuse

Tags: linux, security, domain-name-system

I've got a server which I host my company website as well as some of my clients. I noticed a domain which I created, but never used, was being attacked by a poke and hope hacker. I imagine that the hacker collected the domain from either hitting my DNS server and requesting what domains are hosted.

So, in the interest of prevention and better server management, how would I ask my own DNS server (Linux CentOS 4) what sites are being hosted on it?

Also, is there a way to prevent these types of attacks by hiding this information? I would assume that DNS servers would need to keep some information public, but I'm not sure if there is something that most hosts do to help prevent these bandwidth wasting poke and hope attacks.

Thanks in advance.

*UPDATE*
I realized something in reviewing this further, I saw that in this particular case the attack was not brought on by DNS queries (what ever it would be called), rather a dedicated IP. The account I was concerned with hosts a database for a major website, but contains nothing else. I originally gave the account a dedicated IP and obviously that allowed IP walkers to poke and hope.

The actual (and now better clarified) question remains though, how would or could someone (that doesn't have server access) gather the sites which your DNS server represents?

Answer (score 3):

Since it's your own server, you can look at the configuration files and see what domains you're hosting:

The nameserver program should be Bind, and the configuration file for it would normally be:

```
/etc/named.conf
```

That file, named.conf will contain a few lines for each domain you're hosting.  Look for something like:

```
zone "example.com" IN {
  type master;
  file "example.com.zone";
  allow-update { none; };
};
```

As for preventing the attacks by hiding the information, that probably won't work.  If a hacker can find out your domain name, he can find the IP address of your name server - that's the whole point of DNS, after all.

If you remove (or comment out) the zone entries in named.conf for your unused domains, you'll partially block those attacks.

Comment: Or named.conf.local which is the preferred place for customisations to the named.conf file.

Comment: Thanks for responding Kaerast, but I was looking to see if there was a way an outsider could retrieve a list of domains controlled by a DNS server. I already know about the hosts file and the basics of DNS and TCP/IP as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I imagine that the hacker collected
>   the domain from either hitting my DNS
>   server and requesting what domains are
>   hosted.

Why you imagine this? I mean, I would think first the attacker got the DNS from the published official DNS List in the whois database at the registry, asking "ok, who owns the domain" and "what dns servers are registered for it".

Comment: Exactly. The domain was found first, then the DNS server.

Comment: If zone transfer is enabled to any host, then the DNS server **may** have been located first (unlikely though)

Comment: Haredly. Remember for zone transfer you need to know the zone name first. This means not only scanning ip addresses for DNS server, but also then asking for all zones. Makes no sense. THis attack started on the registry information.

Comment: In response to TomTom, the domain was a subdomain, so it wasn't something that could be found from a Whois record. I didn't originally specify this as I was trying to focus on the how rather than the why.

The 'how' is how could some one request a list of all DNS zones from a DNS server.

The 'why' is that I want to know what is possible regarding searching a DNS server. With this knowledge, I can better understand potential risks.

Comment: @Exit, I think you may have missed a rather important point. There is no request you can make of a DNS server to have it reply with all the domains it hosts. Domain or subdomain, makes no difference to the order the information was found, excluding a random stumble of course.

Comment: John, that is an appropriate answer to the question in the title and as I've tried to make clear, the main question. If there isn't a way to ask the DNS server what domains it has, then perhaps you should provide that as an answer to the question so that I can accept it as a correct answer.

Also, not that it matters much, the reason why I brought up that it was a subdomain is that people were assuming that the hacker found the site from a Whois record, which they didn't and couldn't have.

Thanks

Comment: Sure it could have. Dont assume, exit, that hackers are total morons. He queries the top Domain from WHOIS, then has the DNS servers, then ask those for the complete domain list. In this answeer - he will find the delegations for the subdomains, so he can go on querying those servers (recursively). Saying the information is not available from WHOIS is false - not directly, but perfectly indirectly. Otherwise the subdomain would not be reachable at all from the internet.

Comment: TomTom, there isn't a point to this thread as this is turning in to arguing, not answers. If you want to be helpful, can you answer how someone could query a DNS server to find out what domains (and subdomains) exist? John says that it isn't possible to ask a DNS server what it hosts, and you say it is possible - so I ask you to prove that it is possible.

Comment: I say it is not possible either. I can NOT ask a DNS about what domains it hosts. Zone transfer / nslookup ls requires me to know the zone I am asking for. But I CAN go up on whois and ask for the DNS of public domains, then ask them for their zones hwich will lead me to sub-zone (you call them domain) registered DNS addresses. THat simple.

Answer (score 1):

Many have focused on the background information and picked that apart rather than attempt to answer the actual questions. I have been actively seeking an answer rather than sit back and wait and have come up with partial answers.

> The actual (and now better clarified) question remains though, how would or could someone (that doesn't have server access) gather the sites which your DNS server represents?

Partial answer:
If the BIND configuration (etc/named.conf) has 'allow-transfers' set to 'any', then it is possible for outside sources to get a complete list of zones (domains). How this is executed is still unknown.

> Also, is there a way to prevent these types of attacks by hiding this information?

Yes, by ensuring only a trusted group has access to 'allow-transfers'. In named.conf, use an acl block (Access Control List/Access Control Statement) to define which IP addresses should be given access will block unauthorized access. To set up an acl:

```
acl <acl-group-name> {
<ip-address>;
[<ip-address-2>; ...]
};
```

Replace  with a name such as trusted and list the IP or IP ranges (CIDR block format [/20]) ending with a colon and separated by a line ending. Typically, a trusted list would contain the loopback IP (127.0.0.1), the IP addresses assign in your resolv.conf, and any dedicated IP addresses allocated to your server.

After creating the acl, you can apply it to whichever options you choose. For this, it would be 'allow-transfers':

```
options {
allow-transfers { <acl-group-name>; };
...
}
```

If you want to block a specific IP address from accessing your DNS server, you can add a new acl block and add 'blackhole' at the top of your options block in named.conf:

```
options {
blackhole { <acl-blackhole-name>; };
...
}
```

This is a partial answer, but the most important part was to ensure that someone can't query the nameserver and retrieve a complete list of zones (domains). I'd still be interested in knowing how to execute a DNS zone transfer.

Comment: No, because while zone transfers will allow someone to see what's in a domain, they won't leak *which* domains are available for transfer.